# jQuery: how to show only specific elements of the DOM in a text search

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I'm working on a text search functionality and would like to only display particular elements of the DOM: When a user types in a search term only the divs with class='accordion' and their children, grandchildren etc. should be shown that include the search term in their grand-child's text. I tried the following and the result was, that no elements were shown whenever a search term was entered.

```
 $('#search-criteria').on('keyup', function() {
    var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.panel-info').each(function() {
        var s = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

       if (s.indexOf(g) !== -1) {

        $(this).parentsUntil('.accordion').show();
        $(this).parentsUntil('.accordion').addClass('sh');
       }
       else if ($(this).hasClass('sh') === false && (s.indexOf(g) === -1)) 
       {
        $(this).parentsUntil('.accordion').hide();
       }

    });
});
```

Before I had also tried this instead of the if/else, which seems much more elegant, but didn't work either:

```
$(this).parentsUntil('.accordion')[ s.indexOf(g) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide' ]();
```

Please find the fiddle here  [jsfiddle.net/2vvwZ](http://jsfiddle.net/2vvwZ)

Comment: A fiddle with your content would make this a lot easier to work on.

Comment: Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fwtzC/1/

Comment: Thank you for your great help, Daniel. It looks like what I want, but doesn't work in my case. I'm trying to isolate the problem more and add it to the fiddle.

Comment: Daniel, I did some tests and it seems, if I include your code, it is executed to early, when none of the elements are there yet. I tried document.ready and window.onload and I moved the code to the bottom of the body, but nothing changed the behavior. Any clue?

Comment: Is the content for the accordions generated from an async request to the server?  If so you will have to add the code into a callback.

Comment: Yes, that's how it is generated. Do you mean as part of the $.getJSON()?

Comment: Yes indeed.  You can tack on a .done(function(){ // code here }) to the getJSON

Comment: The code is running at the right time now, however, its still showing the same behavior as before: all divs are gone when I start entering a search query. I will try to see, whether there is a problem in the DOM that might cause this. Thank you so far, Daniel.

Comment: I made a few guesses when is came to the DOM in your example.  If you post a fiddle of the active node, I may be able to help further.

Comment: Okay, here it goes: [jsfiddle.net/2vvwZ](http://jsfiddle.net/2vvwZ).

Comment: I think I got it http://jsfiddle.net/2vvwZ/3/

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. The result looks great in my code. It just seems to not go back to the original view, when I delete the query. Any idea? Also, can you post as a new answer, so I can mark yours as correct.

Comment: I updated it with if (g !== "") and now it shows the original view when all chars are deleted: [new version](http://jsfiddle.net/XKcEB/) Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [`:contains` selector][1] to select nodes that match your search criteria and show them, then hide the rest.

Given that you want to search through elements with the class `.accordion` and show or hide them, you do this:

```
$('#search-criteria').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('.accordion').find(':contains(' + val + ')').show();
  $('.accordion').find(':not(:contains(' + val + '))').hide();
}).on('keyup', function() {
  $(this).change();
});
```

This snippet basically finds all elements with the class `accordion`, `find`s those of their children that `contains` the input value and `show()`s them. Afterwards it does the same but `find`s elements that do `not` `contains` the input and `hide()`s them.

Unfortunately, the selector that comes with jQuery is case sensitive. If you want your code to not be case sensitive, you can create your own selector like this:

```
$.expr[":"].icontains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
  return function (elem) {
    return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  };
});
```

Here I've created a selector called `icontains` that converts the strings to upper case before comparing them. Remember to change the two `contains` in the example above if you want to use `icontains`.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Unfortunately, it doesnt seem to work, see [jsfiddle.net/42rc9/](http://jsfiddle.net/42rc9/)

Comment: @Blitz Sorry, the example had some errors and I hadn't read your code properly to understand the structure. I've updated the example and hope this is what you're after.

Comment: Thank you. It is still not working, I added it [as a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Berenike/BbXqQ/). When I run it in my code, it doesn't find anything after I typed in about three letters (even though the word would be contained). The final result should show only the accordions with the whole panels that contain the search word. Please take a look at the fiddle, if you would like to help.

Comment: I've updated the example. If it doesn't suit your needs 100% your should be able to adapt it.

Comment: Thank you for further looking into this. In the meantime I worked with Daniels solution and built some other feature on top of that, so cannot test this any more. It was still very helpful to learn about the contains selector. Will vote up, once I am allowed.